# Restrictions on residuals and coefficients in regression (DFA)

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, residuals, quadratic-form

The problem is about Deterministic frontier model, a special case of regression where all the residuals are bound to be positive (non-negative). I have a set of values $PQ$ (x) and quantities $Q$ (y) of the product. The main goal is to estimate efficiency frontier of the quantities with respect to values. The relationship is theoretically determined to be convex, which I capture in the following way:

$$\quad y^k = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 - u^k, \quad k=1,...K$$

To find the $\beta$ coefficients we have to solve the following quadratic program:

\begin{equation} \label{eq5}
\begin{split}
min \sum_{k=1}^{K} u_k^2\\
 s.t.\qquad   u^k &\geq 0, \quad k=1,...K\\
\beta_0& \leq 0\\
   \beta_1,\beta_2 & \geq 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We have to minimize squared residuals, while keeping all the residuals positive. Also $\beta_1$ has to be positive (relationship between $Q$ and $PQ$ is positive) and $\beta_2$ has to be positive or zero so we have non-decreasing returns to scale (convexitiy).

I know how to solve this optimization problem in Excel Solver. But I am not familiar with quadratic programming in general so I haven't been able to solve this problem in r. This is how far I have come:

> x<-c(8.1,6.4,6.8,13.3,0.7,2.4,3.5,6.5,1.9,2.8,8.0,6.8,4.6,18.6,1.1,9.5,1.4,3.8,0.7,11.5,7.1,8.2,7.0,7.0,2.2,9.8,0.3,2.5,10.6,1.4,31.0)
>
> Y<-c(15.8,10.6,12.8,26.5,1.3,3.9,6.2,13.1,3.1,4.4,12.6,11.6,9.3,35.3,1.8,16.0,2.7,6.4,1.3,18.9,12.0,14.3,13.5,11.3,3.5,16.0,0.6,4.8,17.7,2.5,71.0)
>
> library(quadprog)
>
> X<-cbind(rep(1,times=length(x)), x, x^2)
>
> s <- solve.QP( Dmat=t(X) % * % X, dvec=t(Y) % * % X, Amat = diag(3), bvec = c(-10000000,0,0), meq=0)
>
> s$solution

I am able to define constraints on $\beta$ but not on residuals. Excel Solver provided the following solution $\beta_0=1.0685,\beta_1=1.715725,\beta_2=0.017476$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you might get better answers on a more R programming oriented site.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is it allowed to ask a reformulated question on multiple sites? Otherwise I will keep the question here. Stack overflow doesn't even support Latex.

Comment: If you get nothing here then I think deleting it first might be the simplest solution.

Comment: I've suggested rspa over on the Stack Overflow version of this question.